# How can I acess a tag by id inside a specific HTML <template> instance using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following piece of code:

```html
<template id="main">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <img id="mimg" class="media-object" src="%placeholder" />
        <div>%placeholder</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

which is supposed to act as a template for a post. The way this is supposed to work is that a piece of js loads in a number of instances of this html code into the page and of course replaces the placeholders with the actual text of the entry.
The problem is that I have no idea how to access the mimg tag inside a specific template instance using jquery.

So the question is very simeple: If given a DOM object, how can I access an object inside that DOM using its nonunque tag (because theres more than 1 tag)?

Comment: `var el = $("#main > .jumbotron > #mimg");`

Comment: Are you asking if you already have `DOMElement` instance in javascript how do you get it's child `#mimg` using jquery?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.  The contents of a template should not be rendered in the DOM as nodes.  It should just be plain text.  You would have to parse it into DOM Elements first, before trying to select them.

Comment: Reference to the details of the contents not being parsed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Comment: Similar to any other really, but you have to select the "content" property: `var templ = document.querySelector("#main").content; var image = templ.querySelector("#mimg");` (idea taken from https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/#toc-using) But using an ID in a template isn't necessarily a good idea really, if you end up inserting the template in more than one place, because you'll end up with invalid duplicate IDs.

Comment: thanks i think this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed in the [MDN Template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) documentation, the contents of a `<template>` are not parsed as DOM nodes.  It will simply contain the contents that can later be parse into real DOM nodes for your use.

Grab the template, parse the html into a jQuery object, and then you can find the inner element by id.

```js
var mainTemplate = $('#main').html();
var $newElement = $(mainTemplate);

console.log( $newElement.find('#mimg').prop('outerHTML') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<template id="main">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <img id="mimg" class="media-object" src="%placeholder">
    <div>%placeholder</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seams to be exactly what I need. The idea is to serve mostly static content and then load the posts in later using templates and javascript. Only question is, isn't it a bit wasteful to take already parsed html code, change it a bit and then parse it back  to  DOM? can't I just clone the children() object, change the placeholder properties and then attach it to the main page?

Comment: As stated in the comments, that's the issue.  It's not already parsed html code.  The whole point of a template is to provide html for the page that can later be parsed into dom elements.  If you do `$('#main').children().length` you will see it returns 0.  That is because the contents are not parsed into dom nodes.  You have to parse them before you can access them with finders.

Comment: If you say this is a problem, does that mean there is a more elegant solution to loading posts with ajax?  Because template seams to have been made specifically for that purpose

Comment: i'm not saying it's a problem.  It seems like you are misunderstanding how the contents of the template are stored in the DOM, suggesting they are already parsed.  I'm referencing documentation and showing you a way to show that that is inaccurate.

Comment: ah ok, so its fine to autoloud posts this way. Just wanna do it the right way, thanks

Comment: Definitely, putting reusable html in templates is a great idea.